# Try, Throw, Catch in functions

Tags: c++

I have a few questions.First of all i`ll give some pseudo code where i want to use this things.

Im doing some homework (realization of bank) and i have next function

```
void MoneyMarketing_Account::Transaction_menu()
{
  int choice, value;
  string login, password;
  cout << "Enter name and pas for account ";
  cin >> login, password;
  cout << "Choose valute and amount" << endl
     << "1 Grn     [amount]" << endl
     << "2 Dollars [amount]" << endl
     << "3 Euro    [amount]" << endl
     << "4 Forint  [amount]" << endl
     << "5 Rub     [amount]" << endl;
  cin >> choice;
  cin >> value;
 if(choice == 1)
     throw(Request_t(login, password, "Grn", value));
 if(choice == 2)
     throw(Request_t(login, password, "Dollars", value));
 if (choice == 3)
     throw(Request_t(login, password, "Euro", value));
 if (choice == 4)
     throw(Request_t(login, password, "Forint", value));
 if (choice == 5)
     throw(Request_t(login, password, "Rub", value));
```

---

```
 struct Request_t {
  string login;
  string password;
  string type;
  int amount;
  Request_t(string login_, string password_, string type_, int amount_) {
    login = login_;
    password = password_;
    type = type_;
    amount = amount_;
}};
```

The first question is - can i use throw statement without try block.
 The second is where this through will go . For instance

```
void foo()
{
  Transaction_menu(); //function that i have shown before 
  Transaction_catch();//function that is supposed to catch request
}
```

Therefore is this throw called in first function going to enter second one?

Comment: It looks like you are misunderstanding exceptions. Exceptions are not for normal flow control, but to handle "exceptional" cases. In this case, it looks like you should `return` a `Request_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can i use throw statement without try block

Yes.  Your `foo()` function is perfectly valid, but...

> ...is this throw called in first function going to enter second one?

No.

If `foo()` calls `Transaction_menu()` in the way you have shown, then when `Transaction_menu()` throws an exception, it will also cause `foo()` to *immediately* throw the same.

If you want to catch the exception, you must do it like so:

```
void foo()
{
    try {
        Transaction_menu();
    } catch (Request_t &request) {
        ...code that goes here will run ONLY if a Request_t is thrown,...
        ...and request will be a reference to the thrown object...
    }
}
```

---

P.S.; "Request_t" is a funny name for a data type that you intend to `throw`.  Usually types that are thrown have names like `TransactionException`.

P.P.S.; Throwing an exception because of something that is *not* an error is very unconventional.  It will make it harder for other programmers to read and understand your code because it completely goes against their expectations.

Also, `throw` is more costly than `return,` so in an application where performance matters, that's another reason not to throw for any other reason besides an error.

Comment: As well appreciate for being patient to explain )

Comment: See @πάντα-ῥεῖ answer below as well.  It's important.

Answer (score 2):

To add upon [@james answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44030732/1413395) (which is technically correct):

**Never ever** use exceptions to realize control flow in your code.
They are meant for exceptional cases and error situations that cannot be covered at the piece of code where they are thrown.

What you rather want is a simple return value for your case:

```
Request_t MoneyMarketing_Account::Transaction_menu()
{
 // ...
 if(choice == 1)
     return Request_t(login, password, "Grn", value);
 if(choice == 2)
     return Request_t(login, password, "Dollars", value);
 if (choice == 3)
     return Request_t(login, password, "Euro", value);
 if (choice == 4)
     return Request_t(login, password, "Forint", value);
 if (choice == 5)
     return Request_t(login, password, "Rub", value);

 throw std::runtime_error("Invalid choice");
}
```